# gae python cron 500 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm struggling to get a cron job working and get a 500 error.

My app.yaml file contains the following handler so it picks up the code

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

This is my cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: my cron job
  url: /daily_batch
  schedule: every 10 minutes
```

main.py contains the following:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/daily_batch',DailyBatch),
], debug=True)
```

and this is how I code DailyBatch

```
class DailyBatch ():
    def get(self):
        myDefaults = DefaultData.query().fetch()
        for d in myDefaults:
            counter = 0
```

If I run this from a url it works fine but gives me a 500 error from cron.  I'm being dumb.  How?

Here's the error info I'm getting

```
ERROR    2015-12-28 10:57:20,056 webapp2.py:1552] this constructor takes no arguments

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1101, in __call__

    handler = self.handler(request, response)

TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

INFO     2015-12-28 11:57:20,068 module.py:787] default: "GET /daily_batch HTTP/1.1" 500 1216
```

Comment: You need to provide the stack trace from the Error 500.

Comment: You don't return anything from the get handler.  Cron could be expecting valid response.

Comment: got it.  thanks.  changed to class DailyBatch(webapp2.RequestHandler):

Comment: right -- in webapp2, handlers (when routed to in the simplistic way) must subclass `RequestHandler`. So please post this as a self-answer and accept it, so the question will properly be seen as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. thanks. changed to

```
class DailyBatch(webapp2.RequestHandler)
```